# C++: Trouble with a nested if loop not ending properly

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, while-loop

stackoverflow. I'm a newbie at C++ and I've got one last issue with my assignment. I'm trying to write a program that calculates the speed at which an object falls from a base height, and displays that information as the height of the object versus the amount of time (in seconds) that it has been falling. This is the code I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    int acceleration, altitude, time;
    double distance;

    acceleration = 32;
    time = 0;

    printf("What is the altitude you are dropping your object from?\n");
    scanf("%d", &altitude);

    printf("Time    Altitude\n");

    while (altitude > 0){
        distance = ((0.5 * acceleration) * (time * time));
        altitude = altitude - distance;
        printf("%d      %d\n", time, altitude);
        time++;
        if (altitude <= 0){
            altitude = 0;
        }
   }

    return 0;
}
```

I know the equation for distance is slightly off, but what I'm more concerned about at the moment is that the program does not print out an altitude of 0 when the object hits the ground. Instead, it prints out -104, and since negative distance isn't achievable, I'd like to fix this.

So my question is this: what is wrong with my while loop/ nested if loop that is causing the program to *not* print out 0 for the final entry in the table?

Comment: Strong suggestion: step through the code under the debugger, and look at how "altitude" and "distance" change as the loop iterates.  I think you'll discover the problem pretty quickly ;)

Comment: `distance = ((0.5 * acceleration) * (time * time));` always evaluates to `0`since `time=0`.

Comment: If you want the program to not print a negative number, then move your conditional (the `if` statement) to be before the `printf()`.

Comment: @Als `time` is increment in the loop, so it becomes non-zero after the first iteration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alter the altitude before printing.

```
while (altitude > 0){
    distance = ((0.5 * acceleration) * (time * time));
    altitude = altitude - distance;
    if (altitude <= 0){
        altitude = 0;
    }
    printf("%d      %d\n", time, altitude);
    time++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton, I feel really dumb now that you pointed that out.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that causes this is your sampling interval: you go in increments of one second, so your program calculates the fall to negative heights. You should change your code slightly:

```
while (altitude > 0){
    distance = ((0.5 * acceleration) * (time * time));
    if (altitude < distance) {
        break;
    }
    altitude = altitude - distance;
    printf("%d      %d\n", time, altitude);
    time++;
```

}

This will not print the time the object hits the ground. You should do this calculation after the loop, using the remaining altitude, speed (`acceleration*time`), and `acceleration`, and solving the equation for the time remaining, getting the fraction representing seconds.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing out altitude before it gets set to 0. Since your formula assumes time happens in 1 second intervals, what gets printed out is the altitude at that time. So if you dropped an object from 20 feet, after 1 second it would be at 4 feet and after 2 at -60 feet- where it hits the ground would actually be 1.25 seconds.